# Multiple Bean Instances in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I was wondering if it is possible to specify x amount of the same bean in a list in Spring. For example, instead of having beans with ids: stage1, stage2,... stageN, as here:

```
<bean id="stage1" class="Stageclass"/>
<bean id="stage2" class="Stageclass"/>

<bean id="stages" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="stage1" />
            <ref bean="stage2" />                
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Would it be possible to do something like the following?:

```
<bean id="stage1" class="Stageclass"/>

<bean id="stages" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="stage1" duplicate="20 times"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup method injection from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html solved the problem. Just needed to make sure the bean I wanted multiple instances of had scope="prototype"

Answer (score 3):

If you use annotation based configuration and you specified list of objects with same interface as dependency for some class then spring will auto-wire aut-wire then for free. Example:

```
interface StageInterface {
    //...
}

class StageImpl1 implements StageInterface {
    //...
}

class StageImpl2 implements StageInterface {
    //...
}

@Component
class StageContainer {

    private final List<StageInterface> stages;

    @Autowired
    public StageContainer(List<StageInterface> stages) {
        this.stages = stages;
    }

    public List<StageInterface> getStages() {
        return stages;
    }
}
```

This is a spring version 3+ feature.

I believe the same is possible with xml configuration as well. In your case that's probably will be the same class(StageClass), but with different configuration parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using standard Spring's default namespace. However you can implement your own [custom namespace](http://blog.springsource.org/2006/08/28/creating-a-spring-20-namespace-use-springs-abstractbeandefintionparser-hierarchy/) where you could support such syntax.

Alternatively, you can implement a [static method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) that would create an ArrayList instance with duplicated elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've looked into static methods and think this may be the way to go. But do you know if it is possible to create unique elements in an ArrayList instance, as opposed to duplicating the elements?

Thanks

Comment: For example, if I wanted 'n' new instances of a StageClass bean?

Comment: Anything is possible, but that would be a different question. I can telly you after you accept my response. :)